# How can I find out the current ClearType (and related) settings in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, cleartype

I want to compare the ClearType settings on two different Windows 7 machines, is there a way I can find out what they are without going through the Windows 7 Clear Type Tuning tool (which will possibly change the settings)?

I'm also interested in any other settings which may affect the rendered size of a given font, the only one I've found so far is 'Custom DPI Setting' under Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old [XP ClearType Tuner PowerToy](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartypepowertoy.mspx) still works in Windows 7 and here you have an advanced view, which shows you what values you use. So you can compare them easier.

Comment: That's the same clear type tuner as in Windows 7.

Comment: no, it has the advanced view. Start the file **"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cttune.cpl**"

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows 10.

Comment: @letmaik the question is about Windows 7. Ask a new question with windows 10 tag

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970267.aspx) article should make the process simple for you. Just compare the registry values and change them as you'd like to.

Comment: Unfortunately I seem to have no entries for any of those registry values.